# How do I call a method in one Blazor (parent) component from another Blazor ("child") component?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I am working on building my first "real" Blazor application. Currently, I am working on a search function that will let the users query an API and get answers back. I feel like I am really close on this, but I need just a little bit of direction.

On the `DefaultSearch.razor` page, there is a text input bound to a `String` which is passed as a parameter to the "main" Blazor component (which is `Index.razor`).

Where I am lost is how to trigger the process from the button I have on the `DefaultSearch.razor` page. There I have an `@onclick(doSomething)`, but I don't know wat to do in the `doSomething` method to start the process.

**Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
@inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory
<div class="text-center">
        @if (fetchedResults == null)
        {
            <HeaderLarge />
            <DefaultSearch />
        } else {
           <HeaderSmall />
           <SearchResultsPage FetchedResults="fetchedResults" />
        }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String queryString { get; set; }
    private async Task GetSearchResults()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8080");
            Search search = new Search(queryString);
            string searchstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(searchstr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(("/api/...", content);
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultSet>(response);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**DefaultSearch.razor:**

```
<div id="SearchContainer">
    <div id="SearchFormContainer">
        <input id="mainSearchInputField" name="queryString" type="text"  @bind="queryString" /><button @onclick()>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public String queryString;

    public void doSomething(){
        // What do I do here?
    }
}
```

**SearchResultsPage.razor:**

```
<div>
    @if (FetchedResults != null)
    {
        @foreach (var result in FetchedResults.documents)
        {
            <div>
                <table class="message">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subject</td>
                        <td>@(result.subject)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>@result.docId</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="message_body" colspan="2">
                            <span>@(result.messageBody)</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public SearchResultSet FetchedResults { get; set; }
}
```

**HeaderLarge.razor:**

```
<h1> My Large Header </h1>
```

**HeaderSmalal.razor:**

```
<h5> My Small Header </h5>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the entire code body of your Index page is doing the search, and should be moved to the **DefaultSearch.razor** control.  So `DoSomething()` should actually be `GetSearchResults()`.  Make sure to add a variable to **DefaultSearch.razor** to actually collect your results, and an event to pass them back to the parent:

```
[Parameter]
SearchResultSet fetchedResults {get; set;}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<SearchResultSet> fetchedResultsChanged { get; set; }
```

And at the end of your search function, you call your custom event:

```
. . .
fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultSet>(response);
fetchedResultsChanged.InvokeAsync(fetchedResults);
```

On **Index.razor**:

```
<DefaultSearch @bind-fetchedResults=FetchedResults />

@code {
     SearchResultSet FetchedResults {get; set;} // not a Parameter
}
```

Comments:

1. To bind a variable, the event must be named EXACTLY the variable name + "Changed"
2. I find that Visual Studio often gives me an error about not being able to convert `EventCallback<T>` to `EventCallback`.  I believe this is an Intellisense bug.  If you get that particular error, try running anyway.

Comment: I have the `Index.razor` doing the work because `DefaultSearch.razor` and `SearchResultsPage.razor` both use data obtained by `Index.razor`, and they are both components of `Index.razor`.

Comment: `DefaultSearch.razor` does not use any data obtained by `Index.razor`-- no Parameter being set in the declaration in `Index.razor`, and no cascading value.  Currently all it does is display a text input and bind it to a string variable.  If you really want to do all your search logic on the `Index.razor` page, then what is `DefaultSearch.razor` meant to do?

Comment: You are correct. I want to search with `DefaultSearch.razor` and display the results in `SearchResultsPage.razor`. I just figured that since they were both "children" of `Index.razor` that it would make sense to have `Index.razor` do all the work and pass data around. I'll attempt your suggestion here in a bit.

Comment: Yeah, if you've done a lot of web programming in other frameworks, getting used to the Blazor way can feel kind of wrong sometimes.  But that's the general pattern-- pass data TO components as variable parameters, and FROM them through EventCallback<T>.

Comment: One last question: You said _"To bind a variable, the event must be named EXACTLY the variable name + 'Changed'"_. Is this something that is built into Blazor (e.g., something I always have to do or it wont work) or is this just for the example you provided? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right.  It's a naming convention.  Without it, @bind-variablename won't show up as a property in your markup for that component.  You can still have an event that passes whatever you want back to the parent, but for 2-way binding, the names have to match.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below helps. Note the OnClick parameter added to the DefaultSearch parameter

Index.razor changes

```
<DefaultSearch OnClick="SubmitSearch" />
```

```
public void SubmitSearch(string action)
{
    if (action == "PerformSearch")
    {
        //any required code
    }
}
```

DefaultSearch.razor changes

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> OnClick { get; set; }

public void DoSomething()
{
    OnClick.InvokeAsync("PerformSearch");
}
```

Comment: Do I move my try/catch in `Index.razor` to the new `SubmitSearch()` method?

Comment: @Brian Sorry, yes that's correct and proabably instead of passing back "PerformSearch" you would do OnClick.InvokeAsync(queryString);